# How to only take certain columns from a line in cascading

Tags: java, hadoop, cascading

Suppose I have a pipe that is bringing a tuple that looks like this:

`[K1, V1, V2, V3]`

where each of them is separated by a tab character. And lets say I only want to extract the first and second last column (V2 column). How would I use an Each pipe to achieve this?

```
[K1, V1, V2, V3]  -> Each pipe -> [K1, V2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Retain](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/javadoc/cascading/pipe/assembly/Retain.html) Pipe and pass the fields that you want to retain.

Your example would look like

```
[K1, V1, V2, V3]  -> Retain pipe -> [K1, V2]
```

Answer (score 0):

pipe = new Each( pipe, new Fields( "K1","V2" ), new Identity(), Fields.RESULTS );